# Generic Swift struct: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segmentation-fault, swift3

I am trying to implement a struct with generic type that conforms to Hashable protocol. Can anybody help me understand why am I getting "Segmentation fault: 11" error with the following code.

I would really appreciate any insights regarding this.

```
struct Pmf<Element: Hashable> {
    typealias Distribution = [Element : Float]
    fileprivate var normalized = false

    fileprivate var distribution:[Element : Float] = [ : ] {
        didSet {
            self.normalized = false
        }
   }
}

extension Pmf {
    init(values: [Element], withProbs probs: [Float]) {
        for pair in zip(values, probs) {
            self.distribution[pair.0] = pair.1
        }
    }

    var probDist: Distribution {
        mutating get {
            if !normalized {
                self.normalize()
            }
            return self.distribution
        }
    }

    subscript(value: Element) -> Float? {
        mutating get {
            if !normalized {
                self.normalize()
            }
            return self.distribution[value]
        }
        set(prob) {
            self.distribution[value] = prob
        }
    }
    mutating func normalize() {
        for (key, val) in self.distribution {
            self.distribution[key] = val / Float(self.distribution.count)
        }
    }
}

var pp = Pmf<String>()

pp["One"] = 4
pp["Two"] = 5
pp["three"] = 5

print(pp)
```

Comment: Your example doesn’t compile because you have no method `normalize()`. Also, could you post code that uses this struct?

Comment: @ColGraff thanks for the reply. However, I do have a normalize function, I didn't add it initially to keep the posted code less. I have updated the question with normalize function. Also, a sample test where Im using this struct. Still, the error is segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Yes. Im trying to convert some of my code written for Bayesian inference in Python previously to Swift for practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need a little trick to define an initializer for a value type in an extension:

Add one line to your `init(values:withProbs:)` as shown below:

```
init(values: [Element], withProbs probs: [Float]) {
    self.init() //<-
    for pair in zip(values, probs) {
        self.distribution[pair.0] = pair.1
    }
}
```

---

Anyway compilers should not crash with SegFault 11. Even if the source code has some fault in it.

You'd better send a [Bug Report to Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/), or to [swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I starting writing a bug report for the similar situation (adding method deceleration using a generic with an associated type) and was getting segmentation faults every possible combination I tried.

I started to write a 'Minimum Verifiable Example' in a playground and found I couldn't replicate the fault.

The only difference between app and playground was that app had protocol and method in different source files.

**I combined the two source files and no more segmentation fault!!**

This took hours of my time to track down, hope it helps someone else.

**Update:** Submitted a bug for this fault, if you're encountering this too, please add a comment to let the team know you've encountered it: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3595